# Removing "" elements from a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list where I would like to remove empty characters: `""`.

I seem to be subsetting the elements incorrectly:

```
> sample2[which(sample2 == "")]
list()
> sample2[which(sample2 != "")]
[[1]]
 [1] ""          "03JAN1990" ""          ""          ""         
 [6] ""          "23.4"      "0.4"       ""          ""         
[11] ""          ""          "25.1"      "0.3"       ""         
[16] ""          ""          ""          "26.6"      "0.0"      
[21] ""          ""          ""          ""          "28.6"     
[26] "0.3"
```

What should I do to subset and remove the empty characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your output, it looks like `sample2` is not a character vector, but it is a list containing a character vector. You should be using

```
sample2[[1]][which(sample2[[1]] != "")]
```

(It would help to include `dput(sample2)` just to confirm)

Or even better, take the character vector out of the list first

```
sample3 <- sample2[[1]]
# or maybe sample3 <- unlist(sample2)
sample3[which(sample3 != "")]
```

Comment: The list, `sample2`, was not equal to the vector `""` so `which` returned a single logical TRUE and that selected the first element of sample2.

Comment: @MrFlick - I don't see the advantage of using `which()` here. Why not just `sample3[sample3 != ""]`?

Comment: @DMC That would work fine as well (assuming there are no NA values in the vector which appears to be the case). I was just trying to address the real problem of indexing the wrong collection.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic solution:

```
> lst = list(1,2,"dog","","boss","")
> x = unlist(lst)
> list(x[x!=""])
[[1]]
[1] "1"    "2"    "dog"  "boss"
```